# cannot debug typescript using Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, nodemon

TS Config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    //     "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    //     "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    //     "strict": true,
    "target": "es2015"
    //     "types": ["node", "reflect-metadata", "jest"]
  }
  //   "compileOnSave": true,
  //   "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Node: Nodemon",
      "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
      "restart": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json snippet

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development-local nodemon",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect"
  },
```

It attaches to the node process that I am starting with npm run debug.
Nothing works however since i can't get it to break anywhere.  Every Breakpoint I set says its an unbound breakpoint.

Comment: ```debug.javascript.usePreview: false``` does nothing behavior stays the same whether it is true or false.